# Hierarchical Classification (on R)

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, decision-tree, knn

First of all, sorry about my english, I am brazilian and I am improving it yet.

I have a hierarchical dataset which I used to use to create flat classification models (NaiveBayes, JRip, J48, SVM)...
For example:

```
> model<-svm(family~.,data=train) 
> pred <-predict(model, test[,-ncol(test)])
```

And then I calculated Precision, Recall and F-measure, ignoring the fact that the dataset is organized hierarchically.

However, now I want to explore the fact that it is hierarchical and obtain different models and results. So what should I do? Considering the same ML algorithms (NaiveBayes, JRip, J48, SVM), how do I create the models? Should I change or include new parameters? Or should I continue as shown in the code before, and just use hierarchical Precision, hierarchical Recall and hierarchical F-measure as evaluation metrics? If so, is there any specific package?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/running-a-model-on-separate-groups to apply models by groups (not particularly hierarchical groups, but you get the idea): https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/running-a-model-on-separate-groups